# skpsmtpmessage: how to to attach a pdf file to a mail

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to attach a pdf file and send a mail with it and a text to explain the content of the pdf using skpsmtpmessage.
I've an error :
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
I probably have an error I don’t see.
The file exist and I've the message "File available"
Can you help me
Thank you very much
Georges

```
{{{

do {
              let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for:        .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
              let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("EngagementsFestivalU13").appendingPathExtension("pdf")
              if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) {
              print("FILE AVAILABLE")
              let fileAttachment = "attachment;" + fileUrl.path
            
              let fileMessagePart2 :[String : String] = [
                kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey:"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"EngagementsFestivalU13.pdf\"" ,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey:fileAttachment]

              let fileMessagePart1 :[String : String] = [kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey: htmlBody]
              message.parts = [fileMessagePart1, fileMessagePart2]
              message.delegate = self
              
              message.send()
                }
            else {
               var style = ToastStyle()
               style.messageColor = .blue
               style.backgroundColor = .yellow
               self.view.makeToast("Le fichier n'a pas été trouvé, veuillez l'envoyer par mail à 'adresse : cfaer@gmail.com, MERCI!!", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom, style: style)
                        }
                    }
            catch {
               print(error)
                    }
}}}
```

Comment: Could you share the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: --SKPSMTPMessage--Separator--Delimiter
2022-05-24 16:56:57.100833+0200 gfer94[4147:129015] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203feba4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a1be7 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2047ef64 _CFThrowFormattedException + 194

Comment: is what you want?

Comment: Yes, there are more, no? You can edit your question with that info.

Comment: 0x7fff203feb87 <+213>: movq   0x660d81ba(%rip), %rsi    ; "callStackReturnAddresses"
    0x7fff203feb8e <+220>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff203feb91 <+223>: callq  *%r13
->  0x7fff203feb94 <+226>: movq   %rax, %r12

Comment: for %r12 I've unavailable (record stack frame)

Comment: I've this thread exception adding let fileMessagePart2 :[String : String] = [
                    kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey:"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"EngagementsFestivalU13.pdf\"" ,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey:fileAttachment] with the fileMessagePart1 it run correctly

Comment: I think that you need in each subdictionary have a `kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey` key and a value. Seeing this line: https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage/blob/master/SMTPLibrary/SKPSMTPMessage.m#L888 that would explain the crash...

Comment: I've changed kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey and some parameters now is coret and the result is OK